# Django returning status code 400 with error message from view

Tags: ajax, django

I have a view that receives a form submit request via ajax. Sometimes it returns bad request based on certain criteria or in case an exception is raised. Now, sending back simple HttpResponse(status=400) is plain simple. Can I send a reason along with it a reason that I can access using xhr.responseText?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I understand you right, you can return 400 with some context:

```
context = {
   'reason': 'your reason'
}
response = render(request, '400.html', context)
response.status_code = 400
return response
```

and for cases with ajax, you just return HttpResponse:

```
context = {
    'status': '400', 'reason': 'you can access this view only via ajax'  
}
response = HttpResponse(json.dumps(context), content_type='application/json')
response.status_code = 400
return response
```

and in your js code:

```
$.ajax({
    // ... 
    // ...
}).fail(function(data){
    var status = data.status;
    var reason = data.reason; 
});
```

Comment: I like this approach of sending the response in this fashion. Thanks @doniyor

Comment: `response = render(request, '400.html', context)
response.status_code = 400
return response`

This is not working. When status code is passed message is not passed.